# How to handle different indices with two different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have two arrays `y=[0,1,1], x=[0,0,4,10,5]`and a Index-array with integers that has the indices of the non-zero entrys from x `I_x=[2,3,4]`.

And idealy I would want something like `y[2]=0, y[3]=1, y[4]=1`

Is there any way to do that for the general case.

I'm happy to answer further questions because I don't think this question is asked well enough.

edit:

```
def function(x,y):
    solution = 0
    for i in I:
        solution = x[i] + y[i]
    return solution
```

This is an example what I want to do, the problem is `i` is from I so y would be out of bounds, what I want to know is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - ```y``` only has 3 elements, so ```y[3]=1, y[4] = 1``` would be out of bounds. Can you work through a simple example to clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still a bit unclear, but I think you are trying to produce an array which contains the sum of the nonzero elements in `x` with the elements in `y` in those positions, and you are trying to adjust it so that *I<sub>x</sub>* will not be out of bounds for `y`. The script below does just that:

```
import numpy as np

def uneven_add(a, b):
    return a[np.nonzero(a)] + np.hstack((b, np.zeros((a.size - b.size))))[np.nonzero(a)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([0,0,4,10,5])
    y = np.array([0,1,1])
    print(uneven_add(x,y))
```